# Removing start and end markers from Google Maps Driving Directions

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a map, with driving directions from NYC to LA.

it works great when i put in the orgin: new york, ny and destination: los angeles, ca

but I want to just use the lat and lng, because I do not want to see the markers Google Maps put on the map.  I would rather just see the polyline from one city to the other city, without the GREEN, Not RED Markers.

I tried using this instead:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(40.7142, 74.0064);
```

but it did not work.  I have it all in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtian/6TCQL/)

Maybe you can't do driving directions with Google Maps without those markers?

Comment: The markers show the start and end of the journey - they should be green-> https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following property :

```
directionsDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
```

right after this line

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({polylineOptions: polylineOptionsActual});
```

[Docs for DirectionsRenderer options are here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get your jsfiddle to work, and I don't know if it's essential to use markers to create the directions you're talking about. Maybe it is, maybe it isn't, I don't know enough about the Google Maps API to say.

However, why dont you just use the markers as you said, but just give them a transparent image?

```
var markerIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("img/blank.gif",new google.maps.Size(1, 1),new google.maps.Point(0, 0),new google.maps.Point(0, 0));
new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: position, icon: markerIcon });
```

`MarkerImage` replaces the standard Google Maps marker image (the red pin) with a specified image.